# Combining else clauses in nested if statements in Rust

Tags: rust

Is there an idiomatic way in Rust to do the following:

```
let z =
    if (condition1) {
        do_something();
        if (condition2) {
            x
        } else {
            y
        }
    } else {
        y
    }
```

Alternatively:

```
let z =
    if (condition1 && condition2) {
        do_something();
        x
    } else if (condition1) {
        do_something();
        y
    } else {
        y
    }
```

Of course, if this was a fully imperative language (and this was in a function), I could combine the two `else` clauses:

```
if (condition1) {
    do_something();
    if (condition2) {
        return x;
    }
}

return y;
```

But I cannot use:

```
let z =
{
    if (condition1) {
        do_something();
        if (condition2) {
            return x;
        }
    }

    return y;
}
```

But since both the inner and the outer if statement (for the first example) must evaluate to an object of whatever type `T` is and cannot evaluate to `()`, that doesn't seem possible to use in all cases, for example, when you are defining a variable by the evaluation of the if-statement. Is there a better way?

Comment: How would you combine the `else` clauses in another language?

Comment: @kazemakase Instead of the if statement evaluating, it would be inside a function that returns something. The inner `if` clause would end with `return x;` and there would be no inner `else` clause.

Comment: @yinnonsanders you know Rust has functions too right?

Comment: @mcarton I do. Putting it in a function would not allow the if statement to use local variables in its environment, so that would change what the if statement can do.

Comment: You said that in another language, you would use a function. What feature of a fully imperative other languages Rust does not have that prevents you to do exactly the same?

Comment: @mcarton I could, but I wanted to see if there's some way to not define a function for the reason I just mentioned.

Comment: @mcarton Python, for example, can capture variables from the environment in a function.

Comment: @yinnonsanders, your example for "fully imperative language" is a valid Rust code.

Comment: @red75prime That's correct, but that would only work inside a function, not in an assignment to a variable

Comment: Also, anonymous functions with captures are not a feature of "fully imperative language", but one of functionnal languages.

Comment: @mcarton That's a good point, what I'm trying to do here is something that wouldn't really be possible in either a functional or an imperative language, but I was curious if there was some way to do so with Rust, since it has significant parts of both. It looks like it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a closure

```
let z = (|| {
    if condition1 {
        do_something();
        if condition2 {
            return x;
        }
    };
    y 
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! Although it could be even better to enclose it in parentheses and add `()` at the end so it evaluates immediately and the result is stored in `z`

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `loop` with a `break` value:

```
let z = loop {
    if condition1 {
        do_something();
        if condition2 {
            break x;
        }
    }

    break y;
};
```

There is an [RFC open now](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2046) about allowing regular blocks to do that to avoid this kind of never looping loop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the RFC! A lot of interesting use cases